# NoMethodError: undefined method `q=' for nil:NilClass: Mechanize; google scraping

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I am scrapping google using following code

```
def google_search(query)
  page = @agent.get('http://www.google.com')
  google_form = page.form_with(:name => 'f')
  google_form.q = query
  page = @agent.submit(google_form)
  page
end
```

but sometimes i get `NoMethodError: undefined method`q=' for nil:NilClass` error. What might be the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the sample code from the docs, there is no form with that name in google search, try "gbqf" but it might differ depending on locale or various settings. When you are using mechanize use "pp" to pretty print the elements during development to see what you are fetching and going next.

Working .rb sample (updated from http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/EXAMPLES_rdoc.html) to get first 10 results by query.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

a = Mechanize.new { |agent|
  agent.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari'
}

a.get('http://google.com/') do |page|
  search_result = page.form_with(:name => 'gbqf') do |search|
    search.q = 'ruby mechanize'
  end.submit

  search_result.search(".//a[@class='l']").each_with_index.map do |link, i|
    puts "#{i} #{link.content}"
  end
end
```

Comment: I had the same problem and I pasted this code and it didn't give me any errors. How do I get it to print something because nothing happened?

Answer (score 0):

The error means that you are calling the method `q` on an instance of `NilClass`. This would happen if `page.form_with(:name => 'f')` fails and so `google_form` ends up being `nil`.

Comment: the question is why does `page.form_with(:name => 'f')` fails only sometimes and not all times?

Comment: @Bhushan - Examine the response. It could be that google has decided you are abusing it and is sending captchas.